# Tunneling from Windows 10 to Jupyter running on AWS

Tags: windows-10, putty, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to access Jupyter notebooks that are installed on AWS and I want to use a windows-10 machine to access it. The jupyter system sits behind a jump host (bastion) on aws. The process works for macs in the following way - Instructions exist to create a ssh tunnel - Magically the notebook is available on a browser by doing localhost:8223 The mac command for it looks like

```
ssh -i /pathto.id_rsa -L 8223:<some name>:8223 -f -o <some other url>
```

What I've been able to accomplish is the following. - Installed putty and pageant. Set up key forwarding on putty and been able to log in to the bastion host. - I tried foxyproxy on chrome but couldn't make much headway there.

How do I access this Jupyter notebook from windows? Again, the set up is

```
 windows --> [bastion] --> jupyter
```

I'm totally lost, any pointers or step by step instructions is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you install the Windows Subsystem for Linux and use the ssl program that comes with that? It should then be very similar to your Mac command.

Comment: I finally got it to work. Using just putty. The key was to check the option that allows localhost to connect on the screen where one adds the port forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work. Using just putty. The key was to check the option that allows localhost to connect on the screen where one adds the port forwarding

Comment: can you share the technical implementation please? I am facing same issue